# Groupby multiple columns and extract top x rows based on column value

Tags: python, pandas

Groupby based on 'month', 'userid' columns and extract only the values as given in 'cntr' column while deleting the rest.

Input Dataframe is:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'month': ['Jan','Jan','Jan','Jan','Feb','Feb','Feb','Feb','Feb','Feb'],
   'userid': ['2345','2345','2345','2345', '2345','2345','2345','5678', '5678', '5678'],
   'cntr': ['3','3','3','3','1','1','1','2','2','2']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data = data, columns = ['month','userid','cntr'])
print(df)
```

Looks like this,

```
     month    userid     cntr
0     Jan        2345     3
1     Jan        2345     3 
2     Jan        2345     3
3     Jan        2345     3
4     Feb        2345     1
5     Feb        2345     1
6     Feb        2345     1
7     Feb        5678     2  
8     Feb        5678     2
9     Feb        5678     2
```

Output required

```
     month    userid     cntr
0     Jan        2345     3
1     Jan        2345     3 
2     Jan        2345     3
3     Feb        2345     1
4     Feb        5678     2  
5     Feb        5678     2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this using [`Groupby.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.head.html):

```
In [3446]: df = df.groupby(['month','userid']).head(df.cntr.astype(int))

In [3447]: df
Out[3447]: 
  month userid cntr
0   Jan   2345    3
1   Jan   2345    3
2   Jan   2345    3
4   Feb   2345    1
7   Feb   5678    2
8   Feb   5678    2
```

Comment: You can run my command on your machine. It runs absolutely fine.

Comment: The result is as expected, `Return first n rows of each group.` I group on `'month','userid'` and return first `n` rows here.

Comment: There are 2 options - not in docs or it should be raise error (I guess second, maybe I a wrong)

Comment: Would be good if you can share the link of the issue that you raised.

Comment: I was right, solution is bad. Check answer in link.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom lambda function in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with [`DataFrame.head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html):

```
#if necessary convert to integers
df['cntr'] = df['cntr'].astype(int)

f = lambda x: x.head(x['cntr'].iat[0])
df = df.groupby(['month','userid'], sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  month userid  cntr
0   Jan   2345     3
1   Jan   2345     3
2   Jan   2345     3
3   Feb   2345     1
4   Feb   5678     2
5   Feb   5678     2
```